# Android: Injecting Javascript into a Webview outside the onPageFinished Event

Tags: android

Hey experts, actually it's a pretty simple question...just don't know about the answer.

I have an Android app, running a WebView that loads a certain page, also part of the app.

At a given moment, i want to call a javascript function inside the WebView page, but i wanna do this outside the onPageFinished event.

Is that possible? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Sure. Use `loadUrl("javascript:...");`, where the `...` is whatever Javascript you wish to run in the context of the currently-loaded Web page. It's basically the same trick that bookmarklets use.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb2) demonstrating this, by pushing a GPS location over to Javascript.

Comment: Look out for the fact that onpagefinished may fire several times for a given URL due to redirects.

Comment: How can you be sure that the page has finished loading before running the script?

Comment: @TacB0sS: As noted in the previous comment, use `onPageFinished()` on your `WebViewClient`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks you for your help, I'm having a serious issue with the Android WebView and injecting the JavaScript at the onPageFinished... it seems like the onPageFinished call is been delayed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995739/log-gate-mdev-action-completed-gate-m-seems-to-delay-execution-on-android?lq=1